# Using loops to draw multiple polygons and discretizing them

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, polygons

I am trying to plot the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian operator with zero Dirichlet condition on following figure against decreasing values of $\varepsilon$.

[image: my region]

I used `Polygon` to create the first figure with $\varepsilon=0.9$:

```
r = Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0.9}, {2, 0.9}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 0}, 
      {2, 0}, {2, 0.1}, {1, 0.1}, {1, 0}}]];
```

Then used `DiscretizeGraphics` to form the region:

```
dr = DiscretizeGraphics[r]
```

Using `NDEigenSystem` the Eigenvalue was obatined.

```
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[
   {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ dr, 1, 
   Method -> 
     {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}
 ];
```

For few epsilons I can use the process described above by changing the polygon, and drawing a new region. Like:

```
Clear[r, dr, vals, funs];

r = Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0.8}, {2, 0.8}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 0}, 
      {2, 0}, {2, 0.2}, {1, 0.2}, {1, 0}}]];
dr = DiscretizeGraphics[r]

{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[
   {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},
   u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ dr, 1, 
   Method -> 
     {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}
  ];

list = Append[list, vals]
Flatten[%]
```

My question is, can this process by done within a loop?

Or is there in way to vary $\varepsilon$ without typing the above code block manually for different values of $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Your drawing and code do not agree on what $\varepsilon$ is supposed to be. In any event: `With[{ε = 0.2}, DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, (1 + ε)/2}, {2, (1 + ε)/2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, (1 - ε)/2}, {1, (1 - ε)/2}, {1, 0}}]]]]`. You can make a `Manipulate[]` out of this if you are so inclined.

Comment: I did what you suggested using `Manipulate[]`. But that is not what I need. 

I need the whole process in a loop in the following logic order:

(1) Draw and store the polygon
(2) Discretize and store the polygon
(3) Solve the eigensystem, append the required value in a list
(4) Repeat steps 1 to 3
(5) Plot the list versus ε

@J.M.

Comment: Then use `Table[]`. I've given you something to start with; you can embed the contents of the `With[]` in there along with the needed call to `NDSolve[]`.

Comment: Can you give me a small example to clarify your point? @J.M.

Comment: guy141 I have given you an example that is more "Mathematica-like" and avoids the use of loops. This is probably what @J.M. was hinting at. I would urge you to spend some time adapting those result to achieve your final goal, rather than trying to follow the procedural approach you pointed out in your comment above. *Mathematica* constructs that avoid loops tend to be cleaner, and sometimes faster as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the `NDEigensystems` code in place, it is not difficult to extend it to work on multiple regions (this is, I believe, what @JM was nudging you towards).

For instance, generate a list of such polygons using `Table`:

```
r = Table[
  Graphics[
   Polygon[{
     {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1},
     {1, (1 + epsilon)/2}, {2, (1 + epsilon)/2}, {2, 1},
     {3, 1}, {3, 0}, {2, 0},
     {2, (1 - epsilon)/2}, {1, (1 - epsilon)/2}, {1, 0}}]
   ],
  {epsilon, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}
 ]
```

[image: polygons]

Generate discretized regions them by mapping `DiscretizeGraphics` over the list:

```
dr = DiscretizeGraphics /@ r
```

[image: regions]

Turn the call to `NDEigensystem` into a function that takes an integration region as a variable using pure functions (look up `#` and `&`), then collect your results in appropriately shaped lists `vals` and `funs`:

```
NDEigensystem[
    {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},
    u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] #, 1,
    Method ->
     {"SpatialDiscretization" ->
       {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}
     }
   ] & /@ dr;

{vals, funs} = Transpose@%
```

[image: results]

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. @MarcoB

Comment: Can this code be modified to store more than one eigenvalue for each figure ( like set 'a' storing 20 eigenvalues of the first figure, set 'b' 20 eigenvalues of the second figure, and so on ) ?

I am trying to see how the eigenvalues change with shape. @MarcoB

Comment: @guy141 I would think it should just be a matter of changing the `1` in `NDEigensystem` to the number of eigenvalues/eigenfunctions you want to calculate out for each shape. You may also have to adjust the `Transpose` expression to better suit your needs in that case, since each output will be a more complex list.

Comment: By changing the `1` in `NDEigensystem` command I got more than one value. But I couldn't extract it out later figure-wise. What kind of change in `Transpose` are you talking about? @MarcoB

Comment: @guy141 Well I don't really know what you want to do with them, but if you request e.g. two eigenstates, then `Transpose@%` will give you a list of lists, the first being a *list of pairs of eigenvalues*, and the second being a list of the corresponding *pairs of eigenfunctions*. I am not sure how you want to visualize them, so you will have to provide more details or, perhaps better, start another question about it, since the issue is not really linked to this one anymore.

Comment: I reformulated my query into another question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119866/set-of-dirichlet-eigenvalues-for-each-figure) @MarcoB