# Deleting circular regions from a larger Circle

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

[image]

I am trying to determine how the Dirichlet eigenvalues of the Laplacian of a circular region change. I would calculate the principal eigenvaluen of this image, and gradually decrease the radius of the deleted regions so that figure approaches a circle.

The position, number and size of the deletions should be random if possible, but once fixed, remain constant throughout the calculation process.

(The general outline of the process I follow is given in my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117937/using-loops-to-draw-multiple-polygons-and-discretizing-them)).

Comment: Like this: `DiscretizeRegion[Fold[RegionDifference, Disk[], Disk @@@ {{{0, 0}, 1/5}, {{2/3, 1/3}, 1/20}, {{1/2, -1/4}, 1/8}}]]`?

Comment: yes basically this @J.M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modified version of my previous answer, which prevents overlap between the randomly selected "holes" in the circular pattern. You can adjust:

- the radius of the `Disk` from which the center points are selected, which is currently set to $0.7$ to only allow holes fully enclosed by the circular region;
- the minimum allowed distance between the selected centers. This is currently set to $0.5$, i.e. more than twice the largest radius of the holes, to give well-separated holes.

Here is the new code:

```
While[
 Not@(And @@ Thread[
     centers = RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.7], 3]; 
     EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[centers, {2}] > 0.5
    ])
]

Function[
  {radius}, 
  DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[Disk[], RegionUnion[Disk[#, radius] & /@ centers]]]
] /@ Range[0.2, 0.025, -0.025]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.
Can this method be generalized for deletions in any shape? @MarcoB

Comment: With this method you can easily end up with inner circles that are so close to the boundary that they go over, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IBVTq.png).  If you wanted to avoid that you'd have to make the `Disk` inside the `RandomChoice` have a radius smaller by 0.2

Comment: @guy141 Sure, just change the region from which you are subtracting. For instance, if you use `Polygon[1.5 CirclePoints[5]]` instead of `Disk[]` as the first argument of `RegionDifference` in the code above, you obtain [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dq3fD.png).

Comment: For some reason, this runs faster if you use `DiscretizeGraphics@RegionPlot[` instead of `DiscretizeRegion[`

Comment: @guy141 Also, JasonB raises a good point about the center selection; you might want to change the code to `centers = RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8], 3]` to prevent clipped disks.

Comment: @JasonB Weird....

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the overlapping of the deleted regions? @MarcoB

Comment: @guy, sure; just track the extant centers, and make sure the newly generated center is further than the length of the smaller circles' diameter to the other centers.

Comment: @guy141 I've included code to automatically reject overlap in the randomly selected holes in a new version. See my updated answer.